# Defining a custom classpath (and binaries folder) for jpackage executables

Tags: java, dll, classpath, jpackage

I am trying to create a Windows EXE / MSI file for my Java application using `jpackage`. By and large, this works, however I am running into some issues for which I require some help:

1. **Defining a custom classpath:**
   I went through [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-C7B49351-7258-4AE1-AA6F-D67859ED716A) that states how to add a custom classpath. The documentation does two things: it uses the variable `$APPDIR` and it uses a `:` separator. However, when I pass this directive to `jpackage`:

```
--java-options "-cp \$APPDIR/config:\$APPDIR/lib\gson-2.10.1.jar:\$APPDIR/lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar:\$APPDIR/lib\mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre8.jar:\$APPDIR/MyApp.jar"
```

... I get this in the CFG file:

```
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=1.0
java-options=-cp
java-options=\/config:\/lib\gson-2.10.1.jar:\/lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar:\/lib\mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre8.jar:\/MyApp.jar
```

As you can see, the reference to APPDIR is removed. Consequently, I get an error when I try to run my executable:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class path.to.my.MainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.my.MainClass
```

The separator slashes don't matter - `/` and `\` have the same effect. If I remove the `--java-options`, the paths are pulled from my `--input` directive, and the `MainClass` is resolved. However, I don't get to see the `config` directory in my `classpath`. I know that there is an alternative [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670541/jpackage-where-should-i-put-resources-folder-for-my-windows-app-image), but I would like to use the `classpath` feature if possible.

2. **Using a folder for DLLs**
   One of my jar files is for MS SQL, where I want to use Active Directory authentication. This requires me to have a specific DLL in the path (i.e. in the Environment Variable `Path`). Is there a way I can make the generated runtime executable look at a specific folder for this?

Comment: If you are willing to use modules, this problem is so easy to deal with. But it means that you won't be using the classpath anymore.

Comment: And to add, `jpackage` was built with modules in mind, and it works better (and more easily) if the application you are trying to `jpackage` is modular.

Comment: @davidalayachew I think the hope is that everything Java will become modular, but `jpackage` was definitely designed with non-modular applications in mind as well. It's also not that difficult; just put all the JARs in a directory and then point `--input` at it. Though there may be a bit of `--add-modules` fine tuning to make sure the run-time image contains the necessary code from the standard library.

Comment: All that looks very Unixy. Even in Powershell, I don't think it's acceptable to use `:` as a path separator in Windows. The path separator is `;` Try `--java-options "-cp %APPDIR%\config;%APPDIR%\lib\gson-2.10.1.jar;%$APPDIR%\lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar;%APPDIR%\lib\mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre8.jar;%APPDIR%\MyApp.jar"`

Comment: Too late to edit - there's the odd `$` still in my post - you need to get rid

Comment: @g00se `%APPDIR%` looks incorrect to me. The final path should contain the literal `$APPDIR` string, it is not an environment variable. If this is powershell, a string literal using single quotes can be used to avoid variable expansion as a result of `$`.

Comment: *it is not an environment variable.* I don't see how it could not be. It looks like a placeholder for the application directory

Comment: @g00se Jorn is correct; `$APPDIR` not an environment variable. [It's a "macro" defined by `jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-34C3BE72-CDE5-469B-BC4D-3D9A6DD2AEEA).

Comment: OK. Let's call it a 'macro'. But those are still *paths* and they have the wrong path separator for Windows. `jpackage` uses 3rd party Windows software to work with Windows stuff

Comment: @Slaw *jpackage was definitely designed with non-modular applications in mind as well. It's also not that difficult;* - You are correct. However, this comment chain was more what I was talking about when I said that module path is simpler. If I use modules, I don't need to know about or care about %APPDIR%, or whatever permutations there exist for it. Ever since those last 2 questions, I have been fully converted to the modules team and hope I never have to see another classpath ever again. And for that reason, I encourage others to do the same if they have the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Defining a custom classpath

The command from the documentation is for a unix shell/platform (as evidenced also by the use of `:` in the class path). On Windows, you need to use `;` as a path separator.

You also need to prevent the expansion of the `$APPDIR` as a shell variable. In the unix shell this is done by escaping the `$` with `\`, on Windows in powershell for instance, you can use a single quoted string (which avoids variable expansion):

```
--java-options '-cp $APPDIR\config;$APPDIR\lib\gson-2.10.1.jar;$APPDIR\lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar;$APPDIR\lib\mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre8.jar;$APPDIR\MyApp.jar'
```

If I use this, it creates a `.cfg` file with:

```
java-options=-cp
java-options=$APPDIR\config;$APPDIR\lib\gson-2.10.1.jar;$APPDIR\lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar;$APPDIR\lib\mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre8.jar;$APPDIR\MyApp.jar
```

Which is what you want.

---

For the native MS SQL library, you should also be able to use `--java-options` to set the `-Djava.library.path`:

```
--java-options '-Djava.library.path=$APPDIR'
```

Then just put the `DLL` file into the folder you pass to `--input`, and the application should be able to load it using `System.loadLibrary` from there.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use both your suggestions and get the application working. Funnily enough, I suspected that the issue was with the file system, but using a `;` separator was causing my IDE to comment out the trailing line in the CFG file, so I relied on the Oracle documentation. The use of `$` was a red herring too, and made me suspect that the executable does some internal translations.